# Spring Security reject access if user have already did action

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring boot web application I have a page where `User` can rate event in which he participated. However if he already did it, he shouldn't be able to open this page. In my `Thymeleaf` he doesn't see `Rate event` button but he can still type the URI and enter this page. How can I provide security so that the user can not get to this page? `User` have list of `Event ID's` that he have already rated.
How can I achieve my functionality?

Edit: Simple check in controller?

```
if( logged.getRatedGamesId().contains(gameId)){
    return "redirect:/users/" + logged.getId() + "/pastGames";
```

Is it good or at least correct way without using Spring Security?

Comment: show us what have tried yet ..

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. I'm looking for best practice. I think about using custom permission evaluator. Would it be good idea?

Comment: What about simple check in controller? If `User.ratedGamesId` contains `Game.id` just redirect to another page with message?

Comment: A check in controller seems fine as this actually checks for some business logic (how many times a vote can be cast) and not a security-related matter (like username/password/token).